How to generate histogram distrbution of odds of this event happening?
I am using R and want to make a distribution of an event happening. There is a 25% chance that this event happens. I want to flip sample this event 30 times. On average, 7.5x this event should occur. However, I want to plot a histogram of how many times this event occurs 5 times, 6 times, 7 times, etc. when there are 30 samples. How would I find the odds of this event happening 5 times or less?

Since it is a discrete distribution a barplot is more appropriate
barplot(setNames(dbinom(0:18,30,0.25),0:18))


You can use pbinom to find the probability (p) of an event happening n or less times out of N. The odds is then p/(1 - p).
p <- pbinom(5, 30, 0.25); p
# [1] 0.2025981

p / (1 - p)
# [1] 0.2540727

Which is about 25.4%.
